# How to build a nested dictionary of varying depth using for loop?

Tags: python, dictionary

Given a Pandas table of thousands of rows, where the left most spaces of a row determine if it's a sub structure of the above row or not.

```
Parameter     |     Value   
'country'           'Germany'
' city'             'Berlin'
'  area'            'A1'
' city'             'Munchen'
'  comment'         'a comment'
'country'           'France'
' city'             'Paris'
'  comment'         'a comment'
'state'             'California' 
' comment'          '123'
```

Where I have information about if a parameter is a list or not.

```py
{
    'country': list,
    'city': list
    'state': list
}
```

I would want to create the following nested structure

```py
{
  "country": [
    {
      "Germany": {
        "city": [
          {
            "Berlin": {
              "area": "A1"
            }
          },
          {
            "Munchen": {
              "comment": "a comment"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "France": {
        "city": [
          {
            "Paris": {
              "comment": "a comment"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "state": [
    {
      "California": {
        "comment": 123
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Since the knowledge about what level the sub structure depends on only the row before, I thought that a `for` loop would be good. But I am clearly missing something fundamental about creating nested dictionaries using for loops. It could be a recursive solution as well, but I am unsure if it would be easier here.

This is my current attempt which is obviously a mess.

```
import pandas as pd
params = ['country',' city','  area',' city','  comment','country',' city','  comment','state',' comment']
vals = ['Germany','Berlin','A1','Munich','acomment','France','Paris','acomment','California','123']

conf = {'country':'list','city':'list'}

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['param'] = params
df['vals']= vals

output_dict = dict()
level_path = dict()
for param,vals in df.values:
    d = output_dict
    hiearchy_level = sum( 1 for _ in itertools.takewhile(str.isspace,param))  ## Count number of left most spaces
    param = param.lstrip()
    if hiearchy_level > 0:
        base_path = level_path[str(hiearchy_level-1)]
    else:
        base_path = []
    path = base_path + [param]

    for p in path:
        if p in conf: ## It should be a list
           d.setdefault(p,[{}]) 
           d = d[p][-1] ## How to understand if I should push a new list element or enter an existing one?
       else:
           d.setdefault(p,{})
           d = d[p]
   d[param] = vals

   level_path[str(hiearchy_level)] = path
```

and the output being

```
{'country': [{'country': 'France',
   'city': [{'city': 'Paris',
   'area': {'area': 'A1'},
   'comment': {'comment': 'a comment'}}]}],
'state': {'state': 'California', 'comment': {'comment': '123'}}}
```

I don't understand how I should be able to step in and out of the list elements in the for loop, knowing if I should push a new dictionary or enter an already existing one.

Any input on what I am missing would be appreciated.

Comment: why Berlin and Munchen are placed in separate dictionaries? can they be in the same one?

Comment: country, state, city values are [list] are they needed to be lists? can they be  just {dicts}?

Comment: Yes they need to be seperate dictionaries, the reason is because of what the output will be used for at a later stage, but I did not include that info since it does not really help the problem. But I can not change the fact that it needs to be a list and separate dictionaries.